# Misleading usage of "former"

Tags: expressions

Political writers sometimes talk about "the former Soviet Union".  This seems to me to suggest that they are trying to distinguish between the current Soviet  Union -- the one that exists now -- and the old Soviet Union -- the one that existed in the past but no longer.  This obviously would be incorrect since there is no current Soviet Union.  Wouldn't it be more appropriate simply to talk about "the Soviet Union".  Readers can be assumed to know that it no longer exists.

Comment: Avoid posting questions which are actually statements of opinion. They are a poor fit for our format because this is a question and answer site. Each post that you enter in a question box is expected to be a question for English experts about how the English language works. See: “[What types of questions should I avoid asking? - Help Center](/help/dont-ask)”. A better place to start an open discussion is our [chat].

Answer (score 1):

Former Soviet Union or FSU is used to refer to the old Soviet Union. *Former* in the sense of an earlier time:

***Soviet Union:***

> ***European-Asian communist federation that lasted from 1924 to 1991 and comprised of 12 main republics*** (Armenia, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Georgia, Kazakhstan, Kirgizstan, Moldova, Russia, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Ukraine, and Uzbekistan) and three Baltic republics (Estonia, Latvia, and Lithuania). Then also called Soviet (from Russian 'sovet,' council) Union, it was the largest state in the world and had a population of some 300 million. ***Now called [Former Soviet Union (FSU)](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/Union-of-Soviet-Socialist-Republics-USSR.html).***

(www.businessdictionary.com)

Comment: And who is businessdictionary.com to dictate what countries and former countries are to be called? I would think a geographic dictionary or gazette would be preferable. *Former Soviet Union* is one way of referring to the region that was part of the Soviet Union before its breakup; it is not a sort of official name.

Comment: @choster - ***they are not dictating anything***, they are just informing that Former Soviet Union is the expression used since the Soviet Union breakup. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=former+Soviet+Union&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cformer%20Soviet%20Union%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @choster - if you prefer Wikipedia “***The post-Soviet states, also collectively known as the former Soviet Union (FSU)***” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Soviet_states

Comment: @choster - or you may like  this site ***THE FORMER SOVIET UNION:*** https://fas.org/irp/threat/prolif96/fsu.htmlthreat. Or other sources: https://www.google.it/search?q=former+soviet+union&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=minv&ei=2opzWt2-JY32kwWLsadg&start=10&sa=N&biw=768&bih=1004&dpr=2

Comment: I am not objecting to term. I am objecting to your characterization of it as *the* term, as if it were the new name of an entity.

Comment: @choster - well, as shown also in Ngram, as well as in a number of sources linked above, Former Soviet Union is probably the more common expression used to refer to the old Soviet Union. The Business Dictionary just states that it is now called that way.